# Object calisthenics. Limiting of instance variables

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I was wondering why instance variables should be limited to two in object callisthenics? Why not three, or four? I understand it is to lower coupling, I was just wondering if there is rationale behind the number two?

Answer (score 0):

https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#8-no-classes-with-more-than-two-instance-variables

> ...the main idea is to distinguish two kinds of classes, those that maintain the state of a single instance variable, and those that coordinate two separate variables. Two is an arbitrary choice that forces you to decouple your classes a lot.